# What is meant with "const" at end of function declaration?

Tags: c++, constants, function-qualifier

I got a book, where there is written something like:

```
class Foo 
{
public:
    int Bar(int random_arg) const
    {
        // code
    }
};
```

What does it mean?

Comment: It changes the type of `this` from `Foo* const` into `const Foo* const`. That has consequences.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. What exactly do you wanna know? If declaring two variables of type Foo will create multiple functions instances of Bar?

Comment: @inflagranti: Yes, exactly this I wanna know.

Comment: Then the answer is no. And why did you assume it would be?

Comment: Some friend told me somewhen... But without the const-tag, would it ?

Comment: @aPoC functions (or here methods) only exist once "in memory" (being `static` or not, it doesn't matter). They get passed a hidden parameter `this` which is a pointer to the calling instance.

Comment: @sbi I think it should be "from `Foo*` into `const Foo*`". `this` is *not* a constant pointer. In the past, some implementations used constant pointer for `this`, as a trick, though. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6067267/10027592) explained it nicely.

Comment: @starriet: Ah, **`this`** is an rvalue, but not **`const`**, right? So my comment was technical wrong, but, sadly, I cannot fix it anymore.

Answer (score 1258, accepted):

A "const function", denoted with the keyword `const` after a function declaration, makes it a compiler error for this class function to change a data member of the class.  However, reading of a class variables is okay inside of the function, but writing inside of this function will generate a compiler error.

Another way of thinking about such "const function" is by viewing a class function as a normal function taking an implicit `this` pointer. So a method `int Foo::Bar(int random_arg)` (without the const at the end) results in a function like `int Foo_Bar(Foo* this, int random_arg)`, and a call such as `Foo f; f.Bar(4)` will internally correspond to something like `Foo f; Foo_Bar(&f, 4)`. Now adding the const at the end (`int Foo::Bar(int random_arg) const`) can then be understood as a declaration with a const this pointer: `int Foo_Bar(const Foo* this, int random_arg)`. Since the type of `this` in such case is const, no modifications of data members are possible.

It is possible to loosen the "const function" restriction of not allowing the function to write to any variable of a class. To allow some of the variables to be writable even when the function is marked as a "const function", these class variables are marked with the keyword `mutable`.  Thus, if a class variable is marked as mutable, and a "const function" writes to this variable then the code will compile cleanly and the variable is possible to change. (C++11)

As usual when dealing with the `const` keyword, changing the location of the const key word in a C++ statement has entirely different meanings.  The above usage of `const` only applies when adding `const` to the end of the function declaration after the parenthesis.

`const` is a highly overused qualifier in C++: the syntax and ordering is often not straightforward in combination with pointers. Some readings about `const` correctness and the `const` keyword:

[Const correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness)

[The C++ 'const' Declaration: Why & How](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html)

Comment: @ereOn, if you liked mutable, you might like this.  The most common use-case for "mutable" is as a modifier for a mutex controlling access to a class instance.  Just because you promise not to modify the instance, doesn't mean that what you read from it won't be modified by someone else holding a non-const reference to it.

Comment: @Janick, I've been learning c++ by myself for a year or two, never see any books cover an explanation like this and I feel it's really helpful. What type of books shall I read to learn these things like this implicit this pointer.

Comment: @Steven: I think the most helpful thing might be to actually read a C book and how some OO like things can be implemented in plain C. From that it's the more easily to see how C++ native OO functionality maps on more lower-level constructs in C and eventually down to the machine.

Comment: A great answer. But I find the 2nd paragraph a bit hard to read, not sure how the text can be improved though. Also if I understand correctly non-member function `Foo_Bar(&f, 4);` won't be able to access member variables in `f` (whether it's const or non-const case), because usually member variables are `private`

Comment: 2 more important points to note:  1) Static data members can still be modified. 2) Bitwise constness is checked here which means that the memory of the object which called the function is checked bit by bit and no change should be made in it. Which further tells us, If there is a int* data member, then the adress that this pointer contains inside the object memory cannot change, but the value at that location which is not part of object memory can change.

Comment: @artm checking access is over and done *before* that. Janick is not describing a pre-processing step. A toolchain will often share a linker between C and C++, in those cases there literally *are* C callable functions as described here, with an extra parameter corresponding to `this`

Comment: What if a const function does not directly change a value, but calls another function that changes a value?

Comment: @LukasThiersch, if const function calls non-const function to change the value, compiler throws **error**.

Answer (score 73):

Consider two class-typed variables:

```
class Boo { ... };

Boo b0;       // mutable object
const Boo b1; // non-mutable object
```

Now you are able to call *any* member function of `Boo` on `b0`, but only `const`-qualified member functions on `b1`.

Answer (score 21):

`Bar` is guaranteed not to change the object it is being invoked on. See the [section about const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) in the C++ FAQ, for example.

Comment: Don't forget about `mutable` keyword.

Answer (score 14):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157458/using-const-in-classs-functions) question.

In essence it means that the method `Bar` will not modify non [mutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2h0ktk.aspx) member variables of `Foo`.

Answer (score 10):

I always find it conceptually easier to think of that you are making the this pointer const (which is pretty much what it does).

Comment: Actually, not the `this` pointer itself is `const`, but what it points to, i.e. `*this` ;)

Answer (score 9):

Function can't change its parameters via the pointer/reference you gave it.

I go to this page every time I need to think about it:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html

I believe there's also a good chapter in Meyers' "More Effective C++".