# Type of 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, class, this-pointer

As mentioned in the title, I would like to know about the type of `'this'` pointer.

I'm working on a project and I observed that the type of `'this'` pointer is `"ClassName * const this"` on windows using VC++ 2008. Well I would want to know what is the need/requirement to make the this pointer a constant pointer. Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The type of this pointer is either `ClassName *` or `const ClassName *`, depending on whether it is inspected inside a non-const or const method of the class `ClassName`. Pointer `this` is not an lvalue.

```
class ClassName {
  void foo() {
    // here `this` has `ClassName *` type
  }

  void bar() const {
    // here `this` has `const ClassName *` type
  }
};
```

The observation you mentioned above is misleading. Pointer `this` is *not an lvalue*, which means that it cannot possibly have `ClassName * const` type, i.e. it cannot possible have a `const` to the right of the `*`. Non-lvalues of pointer type cannot be const or non-const. There's simply no such concept in C++ language. What you observed must be an internal quirk of the specific compiler. Formally, it is incorrect.

Here are the relevant quotes from the language specification (emphasis mine)

> **9.3.2 The this pointer**
>
> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this is
>   a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for
>   which the function is called. **The type of this in a member function of
>   a class X is X*. If the member function is declared const, the type of
>   this is const X*, if the member function is declared volatile, the
>   type of this is volatile X*, and if the member function is declared
>   const volatile, the type of this is const volatile X*.** [ Note: thus in
>   a const member function, the object for which the function is called
>   is accessed through a const access path. —end note ]

---

It is worth nothing that back in the C++98/C++03 times several compilers used an internal implementational trick: they interpreted their `this` pointers as constant pointers, e.g. `ClassName *const` in a non-constant method of class `ClassName`. This apparently helped them to ensure non-modifiablity of `this`. GCC and MSVC are known to have used the technique. It was a harmless trick, since at language level `this` was not an lvalue and its constness was undetectable. That extra `const` would generally reveal itself only in diagnostic messages issued by the compiler.

However, with the advent of rvalue references in C++11 it became possible to detect this extra `const` on the type of `this`. For example, the following code is valid in C++11

```
struct S
{
  void foo() { S *&&r = this; }
};
```

Yet it will typically fail to compile in implementations that still use the aforementioned trick. GCC has since abandoned the technique. MSVC++ still uses it (as of VS2017), which prevents the above perfectly valid code from compiling in MSVC++.

Comment: Exactly what I was expecting. But I do not see that way. the behaviour I'm observing is inside a non-const method of the so called `ClassName` class. Well I get to know the type using the VC++ intellisense which displays the type when you scroll over the variables. Could this be the possible reason why I'm getting incorrect type information.

Comment: @Purnima: The type information you see is probably restricted to error messages only (and to Intellisense and stuff like that). I'm sure the core language sees the correct type of `this`. I.e. if you inspect the type of `this` using `typeid`, it will not have `const` to the right of the `*`.

Comment: @Andrey: Thank u for the prompt response. I indeed checked using `typeid` and got the correct type as expected.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, hmm, if there is no C++0x standard. After that, `this` may have a type of rvalue pointer, if the object is a tmp obj like `ClassName().call()`.

Comment: @neuront: that doesn't make sense. The type of `this` (or any other expression) in a given scope is not determined by the call stack.

Comment: @neuront: If you have a pointer to something, that something is guaranteed to be an lvalue. What I say above applies to `this` itself, not to what it points to.

Comment: @MSalters @Andrey Sorry, but I have made a mistake. Rvalue will only make sense on references, not pointers.

Comment: I just bumped across this piece of text from C++ Primer 4th ed: "In an ordinary `nonconst` member function, the type of `this` is a `const pointer` to the class type. We may change the value to which `this` points but cannot change the address that `this` holds. In a `const` member function, the type of `this` is a `const pointer to a const class-type` object. We may change neither the object to which this points nor the address that this holds." This means VC++ intellisense is correct. I wonder why does `typeid` return the type of `this` inside a non const method incorrectly?

Comment: @Purnima: No. That means that your "C++ Primer 4th ed" is incorrect. I don't know whether this is a deliberate error (for simplification) or genuine error in the book, but saying that `this` is a "const pointer" is always incorrect. Again, `this` is an rvalue of scalar type. Rvalues of scalar type cannot be const or non-const. The fourth edition was published in 2001, which means it is rather old. It probably makes sense to check the later editions. The error might be fixed there.

Comment: @Andrey: I have also referred to The C++ Programming by Bjarne Stroustroup and it mentions the same way.

Comment: @Purnima: The TC++PL book by Bjarne Stroustroup is well-known to contain more than a few errors, presumably deliberately introduced to make things simpler. For example, TC++PL claims that scalar types have constructors, which is absolutely incorrect. Anyway, books are not considered normative references. Only the language standard is. BTW, which chapter of TC++PL did you see this in?

Comment: @Purnima: I just found it in chapter 10 of TC++PL book. Yes, it states that. And yes, that's just another error in Stroustrup's book.

Answer (score 4):

The const means you cannot change what the pointer points to.

```
ClassName *const
```

is much different from

```
const ClassName *
```

The latter is a pointer to an object and the object cannot be modified (using the pointer, anyway).  The former is a pointer which cannot be re-pointed to another object (nor NULL), at least without resorting to nasty casting.

There is of course also the combination:

```
const ClassName *const
```

This would be a pointer which cannot be changed to point to something else, nor can it be used to change the object it points to.

As for why your compiler shows `this` pointers as being const, it does make sense that you are discouraged from making `this` point to an object other than the one it began with.

Comment: +1 good analysis.  In brief, it's the compiler tracking that you can't `this = ...` or `This& p = *this` (given `p` isn't `const`).

Comment: Literal `5` also cannot be changed or assigned to. You can't do `5 = 3`. However, the type of `5` is `int`. It is `int` and not `const int`. To say that `5` has type `const int` is incorrect. The same applies to `this` pointer. It is not an lvalue (just like `5` is not an lvalue). Something that is not an lvalue cannot be const or non-const. For this reason, `this` pointer cannot be `const` and the above analysis is totally incorrect from the formal point of view.

Comment: I prefer `ClassName const *` to `const ClassName *`. Same with `ClassName const * const` to `const ClassName * const`. Read from right to left, and it's easy to see where const is applied.

Answer (score 2):

There were a lot of discussions above and main post didn't present correct answer.
People might not dig comments so its better to share as main port (PS).

I did some investigation on Ubuntu as well as on VC++ but there is no correct output (using `typeid(X).name` ).

---

The type of this pointer for a member function of a class type X, is X* const. If the member function is declared with the const qualifier, the type of the this pointer for that member function for class X, is const X* const.
[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytk2ae82.aspx)

---

Conceptually this is correct also, for normal member function is "X* const" that's why it isn't l-value (as you can't change its contents).

Answer (score -4):

An excerpt from C++ Primer 4th ed: "In an ordinary `nonconst` member function, the type of `this` is a `const pointer` to the `class` type. We may change the value to which `this` points but cannot change the address that `this` holds. In a `const` member function, the type of `this` is a `const pointer` to a `const class` - type object. We may change neither the object to which `this` points nor the address that `this` holds." This means whatever VC++ intellisense was displaying is correct.

Comment: Incorrect. The book, as well as VC++ Intellisense is wrong. Once again, `this` pointer is an rvalue (see 9.3.2/1 in language standard). Non-class rvalues cannot have const-qualified types (see 3.10/9 in language standard). Whatever any book claims is irrelevant, regardless of who wrote it. If some books contradicts the language specification, the book is in error.

Comment: It is quite possible that in early versions of the language specification `this` had a constant pointer type. However, when the C++98 standard was finalized, this was no longer the case. Your books are either outdated or simply erroneous.