# How to understand the C++ implicit parameter "this"

Tags: c++

if we create a class like this :

```
class Sales_data
{
  std::string isbn() const {return bookNo;}
  std::string bookNo;
};
```

And we make a object total;

```
Sales_data total;
total.isbn();
```

The *C++ Primer,* fifth edition, says (page 258),"when we call a member function, `this` is initialized with the address of the object on which the function was invoked "
，it like this:

```
Sales_data::isbn(&total)
```

and the book also write,we can get the bookNo like :

```
std::string isbn()const {return this->bookNo;}
```

I think the implicit parameter "this" just like a pointer,
but i can't see it type，would anybody help me point what wrong i think and what should i do to understand the implicit parameter 'this' and this parameter  works for?

@Jason C
my extra question:
this is a pointer,so it behave like a normal pointer,

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  int a = 1;
  int * b = &a;
  cout << "the b is " << b << endl;
  cout << "the &a is " << &a << endl;
  cout << "the *b is " << *b << endl;
  cout << "the &b is" << &b << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

on my computer the output is :

```
the b is 0110FCEC
the &a is 0110FCEC
the *b is 1
the &b is0110FCE0
```

then ,What's the use of the type of the pointer.

Comment: Maybe this [anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067244/type-of-this-pointer) helps.

Comment: In your case, it is either a `Sales_data *` or `const Sales_data *` depending on the context. Inside `isbn()`, it is the latter.

Comment: This isn't just like a pointer, it is a pointer.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:primes], and "I can't see it type that can be store the address of object" is meaningless. Please restate your question in standard English.

Comment: sorry about that,i already delete it and i will explain my question @Jason C

Answer (score 3):

**this** is not a parameter, it is a way for an object to refer to itself.

If you use visual studio or any modern IDE you can check that **this** has the same type as the class of which it is a member of.

There is a good book called "The C++ Object Model" by Stanley B. Lippman which can help understand.

Answer (score 2):

Even if not defined as such in the standard, every implementation I am aware of makes *this* an implicit parameter to a member function and can be viewed as such.

In C++, you do

```
 object->function () ;
```

In contrast, in Ada the syntax is

```
function (object) ;
```

The object is then an explicit parameter to the member function. The *this* variable is a product of C++'s member calling syntax. Instead of the programmer having to explicitly declare a parameter identifying the object (as in Ada), C++ does this automatically for you (this).

In most implementations, C++ parameters are bound to offsets to locations on the stack or to registers. This is implemented in the very same way as other parameters (either bound to a stack offset or a register).

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a pointer to whatever instance of an object the member function is being called on (note that there is no `this` in `static` member functions or non-member functions, then).

In your case, it is either a `Sales_data *` or `const Sales_data *` depending on the context. Inside `isbn()`, it is the latter.

This (contrived) example illustrates its value:

```
class Example {
public:
    void function (Example *x);
};

void Example::function (Example *x) {
    if (x == this)
        cout << "x is this!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "x is not this." << endl;
}
```

Now if we do:

```
Example a;
Example *b = new Example();

a.function(&a);  // outputs "x is this!"
b->function(b);  // outputs "x is this!"

a.function(b);   // outputs "x is not this!"
b->function(&a); // outputs "x is not this!"
```

Also, since it's a pointer to the "current" instance of the object:

```
class Example2 {
public:
    int k;
    void function ();
};

void Example2::function () {
    k = 42; 
    this->k = 42; // does the same thing as above!
}
```

Comment: actually,in my primary question ""I can't see it type that can be store the address of object" is that i want known where the this parameter store the object address,i try some simple but haven't figure out and i write it on my question.