# concept and datatype of 'this' pointer in c++ and c#

Tags: c#, c++, this

I am a bit unclear about the concept of this pointer.
I know the this pointer in c++ is hidden pointer and it is used to refer the current invoking object. But I want to know if there is a datatype for this pointer, For eg. int *p; states that p is a pointer to an integer. Similarly this pointer points to what? (I mean where is this 'this' pointer declared or written, or where does it exist and how is it written there.)

Second question is in the context of C#
The question is -- what is 'this' in the context of C# if it is not a pointer in C# (I found out it is not a pointer in C# when i tried using the -> arrow operator with 'this' keyword).
And again, what is the datatype of 'this' in C# (I know the answer to the above question relating to c++ would answer it, but I wanted to know is it different in C# )

P.S : I am an amateur programmer, and in learning stage, so apologies for using terms like "how is it written there" instead of the proper technical terminologies in asking the question.

Comment: C# and C++ are different languages. Why do you expect them to be the same?

Comment: I am not expecting them to be same. I just want to know how are they implemented in both the languages. Sorry if the question framing made it look like I consider them to be same.

Comment: The easiest way to think about the `this` pointer in C++ is as an extra hidden parameter. Imagine you have an object `x` of type `X` with a member function `foo` that takes one `int` parameter. When you do `x.foo(5)`, it is effectively the same as though `foo` had two parameters of type `X*` and `int` and you had done `foo(&x, 5)` instead.

Comment: @JosephMansfield: The tricky part of that is that the `const` qualification on `this` doesn't actually come from the parameter `x` but from the declaration of `X::foo`. You can call const methods on non-const objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a datatype for this pointer

The type of the hidden pointer `this` is always the type of the class where the pointer is used. For example, below

```
struct Foo {
    void bar1() {
        cout << this << endl;
    }
    void bar2() const {
        cout << this << endl;
    }
};
```

the type of `this` inside `bar1()` is `Foo*`; inside `bar2() const` it is `const Foo*`.

> Similarly this pointer points to what?

It is a pointer to the current instance. For example, below

```
struct Foo {
    void bar() {
        cout << this << endl;
    }
} foo;
```

the pointers `this` inside `bar()` and the expression `&foo` point to the same object.

> what is `this` in the context of C# if it is not a pointer?

C# has no pointers<sup>*</sup>, but its concept of object references is reasonably similar. In C#, `this` represents a reference to the current object. The type of `this` is the type of the class inside which it is referenced.

Note that the runtime type of the object pointed to by `this` may be different - for example, it could be a subclass. However, the static type of the pointer `this` matches the type of the class inside which the pointer `this` is referenced.

<sup>*</sup> unless you venture into unsafe context, anyway.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks for the comment. When you see trivial issues like missing asterisks, feel free to edit the answer - you don't even need an approval for this :)

Comment: Sure, but in this case I thought it was a genuine error ;)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the this pointer is an implicit parameter passed to all nonstatic member functions (passed to them as a hidden argument). Have a look here for more explanations: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_this_pointer.htm and here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/this-pointer-in-c/, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dddwwd.aspx.

In C# the "this" is a reserved keyword which is a reference to the object for which the method is running. As you know in C# you don't use pointers, but you use references to objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's IMHO a useful reference, that describes the problem pretty fine: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dddwwd.aspx)

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers.

Comment: Sorry. I thought it's a bad idea to rewrite the same text here

Comment: @Nickon: It is. Summarizing the important points is a good idea, however.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `this` pointer in C++ has a type.

```
class A
{
public:
  void func() {}
}
```

Inside `func` type of `this` is:-

```
A * const          //for non-const functions.
A const * const    //for const functions.
```

Comment: While it behaves like an `A * const`, technically, it's not because it's an rvalue: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6067267/3764814)

Answer (score 0):

`this` is most certainly a pointer in C++, in class `Foo` it will be of the type `Foo *`, unless you're in a `volatile` or `const` method - in that case those 2 modifiers will propagate to the `this` type.

Similarly in C# `this` is just a magical reference variable of the current object's type.