# the type of this* in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, const-pointer

it might sound stupid.in C++prime 5th edition P258,it says:

> by default, the type of this is a const pointer to the nonconst version of the class type.for example,by default, the type of this in a Sales_data member function is Sales_data *const.

i can understand that for this* is a const pointer which means the object it points once initialized cannot change.but then it says:

> although this is implicit, it follows the normal initialization rules,which means that(by default)we cannot bind this to a const object.

but i wrote the following codes,it was still compiled fine:

```
class Test{
public:
    Test() = default;
    Test(const string &s): teststr(" ") {};
    Test(int a) : testint(a) {};
    Test(const string &s, int a): teststr(s), testint(a) {};
    string getstr() const { return teststr; };
    int getint() { return testint; };   //there is no const here
private:
    string teststr;
    int testint = 0;
};

int main(){
    Test a("abc",2);

    cout << a.getint() << " ";
    cout << a.getstr() << endl;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

so my question is :
if the compiler can compile it fine whether there is a 'const' or not,why does it matter?
and then the book says:

> after all,the body of isbn doesn't change the object to which this points, so our function would be more flexible if this were a pointer to const.

and i'm wondering what is the flexiblity is?would you show me some examples?

Comment: The book is misleading. `this` isn't a "const pointer". It's a keyword, and when evaluated it produces a prvalue of a suitable pointer type. Since it's a prvalue, you can't modify it, just like you can't say `(1 + 2) = 3`.

Comment: You are confusing "const pointer" (pointer that can't be made to point to a different object) and "pointer to const" (pointer to an object that you aren't allowed to change through the pointer).

Comment: As for the example you want, change the first line of your `main()` to `const Test a("abc",2);` and you will note that you can no longer call `getint()` but you *can* continue to call `getstr()`. Methods that don't change the object should be declared `const` because then they can be used when given a `const` object (or reference/pointer-to a `const` object).

Comment: Your quote specifically says "by default, the type of this is a const pointer **to the nonconst version of the class type**.for example,by default, the type of this in a Sales_data member function is Sales_data *const"

Comment: you keep typing `this*` which is not a thing. Just plain `this`, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type of 'this' pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067244/type-of-this-pointer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For beginners, `this` is often depicted as a constant pointer.

However, `this` is actually a prvalue (pure rvalue) of pointer type. You can't assign anything to prvalues of fundamental type, which implies the "const-ness" of `this`.

The exact type of `this` depends on the cv-qualification of the method. A rule of thumb is that the cv-qualification is simply prepended to the usual pointer type - i.e., if a method of `Class` is marked `const`, then the type is `const` `Class*`.

> if the compiler can compile it fine whether there is a 'const' or
>   not,why does it matter?

If (and only if) the pointee type of `this` is `const`, you can't modify the members of the class.

```
Class const* ptr; // ptr->data is also const, not modifiable through this pointer

Class* ptr; // ptr->data isn't const - can be modified.
```

The `const`-qualifier on methods allows you to distinguish between methods for `const` objects and methods for non-`const` ones, which is often a necessity.

Answer (score 7):

According to the C++ Standard (9.3.2 The this pointer)

> 1 In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this
>   is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for
>   which the function is called. The type of this in a member function of
>   a class X is X*. If the member function is declared const, the type of
>   this is const X*, if the member function is declared volatile, the
>   type of this is volatile X*, and if the member function is declared
>   const volatile, the type of this is const volatile X*.

As you see there is nothing said that `this` has type `ClassTYpe * const` of `ClassType const * const`. It is a prvalue that may not be modified as any prvalue except that for a prvalue of a class type you may call non-const member functions..

As for you then you mix two types a constant pointer and a pointer that points to a constant data.
For example this declaration

```
const ClassType *p;
```

does not declare a constant pointer. So the pointer itself may be not initialized. On the other hand thsi declaration

```
ClassTYpe * const p = new ClassTYpe;
```

declares a constant pointer and the pointer itself shall be initialized as any other constant.

As for this quote from your book

> after all,the body of isbn doesn't change the object to which this
>   points, so our function would be more flexible if this were a pointer
>   to const

Then it means that it would be better to define the function with qualifier const. In this case it could be called for constant and non-constant objects. Otherwise it may be called only for-non constant objects because within the function the pointer type of `this` is not `const ClassTYpe *`.

Comment: _"It is a prvalue that may not be modified as any prvalue"_ That's only true for prvalues of non-class type, so _"any"_ is wrong.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit You may call non-const member functions for a prvlaue of a class type but you may not change data members of the class directly.

Comment: Correct, but you may do so through a call to a member function. To say that you cannot modify the object is plain wrong.

Answer (score 5):

> *"i can understand that for this* is a const pointer which means the object it points once initialized cannot change.but then it says:"*

No, you got this wrong. Being `this` a *const pointer* means, you cannot change the pointer value itself like

```
 class MyClass {
      void foo() {
          MyClass a;
          this = &a; // <<< Compiler error
      }
 }
```

The type of `this` actually appears as

```
 MyClass * const this;
```

and for `const` instances or references

```
 MyClass const * const this;
```

[Note this is different from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const)

```
 const MyClass* some_const_instance_pointer;
```

Comment: "Note this is different from" You are wrong. There is no difference at all.:)

Comment: Though you updated your post nevertheless I do not see a difference.:)

Answer (score 5):

The "flexibility" is that you can call a `const` function on any object, constant or not. You can't call a non-`const` function on a `const` object (or reference/pointer to `const`).

So the following would fail:

```
const Test c;
cout << a.getint() << " ";   // ERROR: non-const function
cout << a.getstr() << endl;  // OK: const function
```

As well as this flexibility, declaring a member function `const` is a good idea since that will prevent you from accidentally modifying the object in a function that's not supposed to.

Answer (score 4):

Two questions two answers.

The `this` pointer cannot be reassigned. That's what is meant by `const` in this case. You can change the contents of the object that `this` points to but you cannot change which object it points to.

The extra flexibility of making a method `const` is that it can be used on both `const` and non-const objects. A non-const method cannot be used on a `const` object.

Example:

```
class A {
    int a;
    public:
    int method() const {
        return a;
    }
};

void f() {
    A a;
    const A ca;

    a.method();
    ca.method();
}
```