# Is it possible to change the type of the 'this' keyword?

Tags: c++, gcc, corba

Now this may seem like a strange question, but I've come accross a compiler error that has just blown my mind and even though there is a fix, I'd like to know why it breaks.

So the pretense is I'm using an API called Corba, it's used for RPC in short. In my program I am having to create an object which derives from a Corba object.

```
class MyClass : public CorbaClass;
```

Simple stuff, now in one of the methods of `MyClass` I am calling a function which requires a `CorbaClass*`, so I simply pass in the `this` pointer, note that the method is **not** a const method so surely this should work fine ?

However I get an error when compiling which states that the parameter I'm trying to pass is actually of type `CorbaClass* const`. Now you can imagine my confusion, surely that is not possible, that would require `this` to be an lvalue would it not ? So all of a sudden this has me questioning parts of my knowledge of C++ itself !

Now it turns out in the documentation of TAO (the specific implementation of Corba I'm using) that they actually have a snippet of code for this exact situation and I see they do something strange. Instead of directly passing `this`, they call a method `_this()` and pass the return from that through, so I did a bit of digging and found the method was declared in the Corba base class as:

```
CorbaClass* _this(void);
```

Now this seems completely insane to me, but maybe that's because I've never come accross it before, does anyone know why any of the weird stuff with `this` is happening ?

I believe the compiler I'm using is GCC 4.5.1

**Edit:**
Some example code

MyClass.h

```
    class MyClass
    : public POA_NotifyExt::ReconnectionCallback
{
public:
    void Initialise();

private:
    NotifyExt::ReconnectionRegistry_var m_ReconnectionRegistry;
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
void Initialise()
{
    m_ReconnectionRegistry->register_callback( this );
}
```

Generates error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘NotifyExt::ReconnectionRegistry::register_callback(MyClass* const)’
orbsvcs/NotifyExtC.h:491:63: note: candidate is: virtual NotifyExt::ReconnectionRegistry::ReconnectionID NotifyExt::ReconnectionRegistry::register_callback(NotifyExt::ReconnectionCallback*)
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067244/type-of-this-pointer

Comment: I don't think "pretense" means what you think it means!

Comment: Are you sure you mean `CorbaClass* const` and not `CorbaClass const*`?

Comment: _"the method is not a const method"_ It must be, mate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `this` is behaving as intended. Maybe your code isn't, but that's not your question.

Comment: Can you link to this "snippet" of TAO you refer to?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, it isn't, even if it was this would be a const CorbaClass* not a CorbaClass* const.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes I am 100% sure

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - your code which contains the failing call (including types of anything relevant involved), and the declaration of the function whose call fails.

Comment: @abcthomas: True. But you cannot be 100% sure, because this makes no sense. Be less sure, and more evidence-showing.

Comment: lol TAO docs are paywalled

Comment: I know it doesn't hence my confusion, I will post an MCVE but I'm not sure how much more information it will provide.

Comment: @abcthomas: It will provide infinitely more than we have at present! Or, the act of constructing it will reveal to you the bug in your code. That's what usually happens.

Comment: If your compiler thinks that `this` is a `T* const` then it is noncompliant. More likely you are misinterpreting the error message. But, not considering this possibility, you did not even show it to us!

Comment: Not knowing a thing about TAO, is `POA_NotifyExt::ReconnectionCallback` a derivative of `NotifyExt::ReconnectionCallback` ? If not, then your class isn't either, and therefore doesn't fulfill the requirements of the parameter.

Comment: Aha fml ! No it isn't it's a different class and from what I can tell they share no ancestry. Thanks, completely couldn't see that, doesn't help that the '_this()' method returns a different type. But one last question, why does my error state I'm giving a MyClass* const ?

Comment: That seems odd to me as well, a strange way of telling you `this` is non-modifiable. I'd be curious if `clang` reported a different message, something to the effect of "Candidate function not viable, no known conversion from `MyClass*` to `NotifyExt::ReconnectionCallback*`", which would have been considerably more informative.

Comment: @abcthomas `this` is an rvalue and cannot be assigned to. So it's possible it's implemented as `TheClass * const` internally, so that's what the compiler shows.

Comment: @Angew I suspect similar. A more modern gcc may report differently as well.

Comment: Interesting, well thanks, yeah this compiler is quite old but unfortunately it's the build chain which has been forced upon me by my customer ! Thanks for the feedback I'll put this down to a quirk of the compiler message.

Answer (score 1):

`register_callback` expects a `NotifyExt::ReconnectionCallback`, not a `POA_NotifyExt::ReconnectionCallback` (note the different namespaces).

`MyClass` is what is called a Servant: a server-side object implementing a CORBA interface.

Since CORBA aims at being location and language independent, the client of an object does not refer directly to the Servant; it uses an "object reference" which contains the information necessary to reach the object. You thus need to pass an object reference to the CORBA object implemented by the `MyClass` Servant.

One way to obtain such a reference is to use the `_this()` member function.