# Determining the type of a variable

Tags: c++

You are given a variable p defined in C++ program. Is it possible to find out if it's a pointer to something or a normal variable?
specifically, suppose there is a class Test

```
    class Test
    {
    public:
        int test1(int i)
        {
            
        }
        static int test2(int i)
        {
        }
const int test3(int i)
    {
    }

}
```

Now `this` is a variable accessible inside test1 and test2 and test3, But I want to determine the type of `this` inside each of these functions. It could be `Test,` `Test const,` `Test* const` etc...
How can I figure this out myself, or is there any alternate documentation for the same?

Comment: And what would you _do_ with this information, exactly? That will help us help you.

Comment: `this` is a pointer to the calling object. The member function doesn't affect it at all.

Comment: Note that `this` is *not* accessible in `test2` -- `test2` is a static member.

Comment: A first hint is that you may look at type_traits "https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits" or  here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types

Comment: In the question's code, the simple answer is to glance at the function declaration and you'll immediately know from that with some fundamental C++ knowledge. If the real problem is more complicated to the point where that won't work, it's helpful to give a little more context.

Comment: FYI: [SO: Type of 'this' pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6067244/7478597)

Comment: If the nonstatic member function is declared const, then the `this` pointer is pointing to a  const object.  Likewise, if the nonstatic member function is not declared const, then the `this` pointer points to a non-const.  There is no checking necessary, just look at your function signature and you know.  static members do not have any `this` poitner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use, having written `#include<type_traits>`

```
std::is_const<decltype(this)>::value
```

within a member function. If that member function is `const` then this value will be `true`, else it will be `false`.

Note there is no `this` in a `static` member function, and that `this` is always a pointer type in C++.

Comment: Thanks. So I understand that this will always be a pointer type in C++, But could it be a `const`  pointer?

Comment: @daniel -- `this` is **always** a `const` pointer; you cannot modify its value. You're right that `this` can  point at a `const` object or at a non-`const` object.