# What does it mean when const is put after a function's declaration?

Tags: c++, constants

I can run the following code without problem. I notice both a.bytes and bytes in main changed to "B".
So what does the "const" do in A's get() function? Is it going to be a problem in my usage of changing the bytes I get from A as below?

Note: I don't care if A's value will change. I just want to know if I will encounter unpredictable problems, especially when I free A at its deconstructor no matter whatever crazy action I take with the bytes in main.

```
class A{
public:
    A(){
        bytes = (char *)malloc(12);
        bytes[0] = 'A';
        bytes[1] = 0;
    }
    ~A(){
        free(bytes);
    }
    char * get() const{
        return bytes;
    }
    char * bytes;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;
    char * bytes = a.get();
    bytes[0] = 'B';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `malloc` and `free` in a C++ program?

Comment: And please don't use c-style casts in C++, `bytes = (char *)malloc(12);` is just bad

Comment: @UnholySheep, in what situation would c-style cast of pointer returned by `malloc` have unexpected results?

Comment: It's just a simplified version of cocos2d-x's Data class (ver 3.x)

Comment: @user2079303 while it may not necessarily have unexpected results there are certain reasons why you should not do it. These have been discussed often enough on various sites (including SO). Even so, you should not use C-style casts in C++, as this is a bad habit that can easily lead to errors and unexpected behaviour

Comment: The first two "Related" links on the right of the page: http://stackoverflow.com/q/751681/1918193 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1143262/1918193 perfectly answer this question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is meant with "const" at end of function declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141087/what-is-meant-with-const-at-end-of-function-declaration)

Comment: In addition to the method being `const` and thus not allowing it to modify the object contents (`*this`), it should return a pointer that is also `const` thus not immediately allowing the internals to be altered either (as does in the sample). Hence favour a signature such as `char const * get() const`. Const-correctness involves more that just marking a method as `const`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It simply means that the *member* function will not (and can't) modify any internal data inside the object.

It also causes the `this` variable inside the member function to be `const`.

Comment: I see. Is there any chance that it causes problem when ~A() is called?

Comment: I don't agree with you. You can want a const pointer pointing on a non-const value. But, here it's clearly not the case.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I disagree on the undefined behavior. `const` can always be legally cast away unless the original object is declared `const`. Of course, this would be horrible programming practice but a compiler cannot optimize on this.

Comment: As making this pointer const, Does it prevent the returning value out of scope?

Answer (score 3):

It means that the function doesn't modify the members of the class (only members with the key-word `mutable` can be modified).
It also means that the function doesn't call other non-const functions of the class.

Comment: But I see A.bytes changed after I run the program

Comment: No, the address in the pointer doesn't change. Mayby what you have pointed by A.bytes changes. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To add a note, when const put after a member function it means that the "this" pointer passed to the member function will be const,
Hence only mutable and or read only operations are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

It means you can only modify `mutable` member variables of the object. This is useful if you have a `const` object, but still want to use some non-mutating member functions.