# C++ correct input validation for constructor initializers on const types

Tags: c++

Is this really the correct way to validate constructor input for C++ initializer lists and const member types?

Am just a little taken aback as to how verbose this, usually trivial, action is compared to other languages such as Java/C#...

```
class irc_nickname
{
private:
    static const std::regex nick_regex_;
    const std::string name_;

    const std::string & verify_name(const std::string & name)
    {
        if (!irc_nickname::is_valid(name))
            throw std::invalid_argument("The provided name does not conform to irc nickname requirements.");
        return name;
    }

public:
    irc_nickname(const std::string & name) : name_(verify_name(name)) {};

    static bool is_valid(const std::string & name)
    {
        return std::regex_match(name, nick_regex_);
    }
};
```

Of course I can't just perform the validation in the constructor as `name_` is a const type and would already be initialized within the constructor.

If not, what is the de-facto way of doing this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you have here. It's a perfectly acceptable way of validating a const member field. Now, if you're willing to walk on the wild side and *not* use a const member field, then you can use [const member functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3141107/2297365) instead. This is a reasonable design alternative since your `name_` field is already private, so anything that could potentially modify it must use member methods from your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... so we have a "problem" statement...

> taken aback as to how verbose

...and an assertion about one option being unavailable:

> can't just perform the validation in the constructor as name_ is a const type and would already be initialized within the constructor

The latter is wrong... you *can* assign to the data member then validate it in the constructor, and it simplifies the code a smidge (though makes it a smidge less efficient in the throwing case).  As long as any exception's thrown before the constructor completes, the data members will still be "destructed" properly.

One reason for the verbosity is that you've chosen to make `is_valid()` a public non-member function, which necessitates the parameter passing.  You've also chosen to put `verify_name()` into a separate, reusable function, rather than perform the check directly in the constructor - also more verbose, but potentially reasonable if it will be reused (e.g. by `operator=`) or the constructor's likely to be complicated by too many concerns.

Moving the public members to the top of the class (a widely followed practice which aids in quickly grasping the client-facing functionality), and functions before data, we have:

```
class irc_nickname
{
  public:
    irc_nickname(const std::string& name) : name_(name) { verify_name(); }

    static bool is_valid(const std::string& name)
    {
        return std::regex_match(name, nick_regex_);
    }

  private:
    void verify_name()
    {
        if (!is_valid(name_))
            throw std::invalid_argument("The provided name does not "
                            "conform to irc nickname requirements.");
    }

    static const std::regex nick_regex_;
    const std::string name_;
};
```

If you don't really need a reusable `verify_name()` - as implied by your own answer - but do want the static public `is_valid()`, you end up with:

```
class irc_nickname
{
  public:
    irc_nickname(const std::string& name)
      : name_(name)
    {
        if (!is_valid(name_))
            throw std::invalid_argument("The provided name does not "
                            "conform to irc nickname requirements.");
    }

    static bool is_valid(const std::string& name)
    {
        return std::regex_match(name, nick_regex_);
    }

  private:
    static const std::regex nick_regex_;
    const std::string name_;
};
```

You could also factor out a reusable regexp-validated-string class that `irc_nickname` uses to store `name`, keeping `irc_nickname` less cluttered.

Personally, I tend to use a macro to throw on a failed assertion:

```
#define ASSERT_THROW_TYPE(X, TYPE, MSG) \
    do { \
        if (X) break; \
        std::ostringstream oss("ASSERT FAILED !" #X " "); \
        oss << __FILE__ << ':' << __LINE__ << ' ' << X; \
        throw TYPE(oss.str()); \
    } while (false)

#define ASSERT_INVALID_ARG(X, MSG) ASSERT_THROW_TYPE(X, std::invalid_argument, MSG)
#define ASSERT_RUNTIME(X, MSG) ASSERT_THROW_TYPE(X, std::runtime_error, MSG)
...etc...
```

Then you can reduce the `if (!is_valid(name_)) throw ...` bit to the more declarative and informative:

```
ASSERT_INVALID_ARG(is_valid(name_), "The provided nickname '" << name_
    << "' does not conform to irc nickname requirements.");
```

Comment: Beautiful :)
Compile-time checking with the assertion is even better.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera: just to be clear - the code above won't do compile-time checking even if the `name` is known at compile time - that would actually be quite tricky but should be possible with C++11 (e.g. see [here](http://cpptruths.blogspot.hk/2011/07/compile-time-regex-matcher-using.html)); of course such a check would need to generate a static assertion or compile error rather than a runtime exception.

Comment: hm, ok. Why would one then use the lengthy asserts way over throwing the exception?

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera: the macro definitions for the assert support are lengthy, but only needed once to support an arbitrarily large project; the *use* of the assert macro is *slightly* shorter than the `if`/`throw` form, it's more declarative, it expresses what's wanted rather than uinwanted which some people argue reads better (being more like a "precondition"), and the macro injects the filename, line number, a copy of the source code (i.e. `"is_valid(name_)"`), and lets the calling code stream arbitrary values (above, `name_`).  It can be customed, adding e.g. timestamps, pid, thread id....

Answer (score 0):

I guess one could also use a lambda, but I haven't been able to find any better, or seemingly correct, intended, way of doing this...

Also, both explicit function and lambdas in this case will get inlined so neither is more performant over the other.

```
class irc_nickname
{
private:
    static const std::regex nick_regex_;
    const std::string name_;

public:
    irc_nickname(const std::string & name)
    : nickname_([](const std::string & name) -> const std::string &
    {
        if (!irc_nickname::is_valid(name))
            throw std::invalid_argument("The provided name does not conform to irc nickname requirements.");
        return name;
    }(name)) {};

    static bool is_valid(const std::string & name)
    {
        return std::regex_match(name, nick_regex_);
    }
};
```

Alternative 2:

```
class irc_nickname
{
private:
    static const std::regex nick_regex_;
    const std::string name_;

public:
    irc_nickname(const std::string & name)
    : nickname_([&name]() -> const std::string &
    {
        if (!irc_nickname::is_valid(name))
            throw std::invalid_argument("The provided name does not conform to irc nickname requirements.");
        return name;
    }()) {};

    static bool is_valid(const std::string & name)
    {
        return std::regex_match(name, nick_regex_);
    }
};
```

From huu:
There's nothing wrong with what you have here. It's a perfectly acceptable way of validating a const member field. Now, if you're willing to walk on the wild side and not use a const member field, then you can use const member functions instead. This is a reasonable design alternative since your name_ field is already private, so anything that could potentially modify it must use member methods from your class.