# C++ Error: no viable conversion from returned value of type

Tags: c++, function, vector

I am trying to pass a vector to a function as an `argument/parameter` in order to `print/return` contents of that `list/array/vector` but when I compile the code I'm facing this error:

[image]

here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int printVector(vector<int> vec_name){
  return copy(vec_name.begin(), vec_name.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout," ")); // returning contents of the array/vector
}

int main(){
  vector<int> array;

  for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
    array.push_back(i); // inserting values to the array
  }

  printVector(array); // Printing the vector array

}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

Comment: if you want his code to just work as it is, change the int return type on printVector()  to auto. if you just want to print the values in the vector don't use copy, loop through the vector and print each value.

Comment: Thanks alot @DanielCollier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED:

used for loop in order to print each value from the vector:

```
void printVector(vector<int> &vec_name){
  for(int i=0; i<vec_name.size(); i++){
    cout << vec_name[i] << " ";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void printVector(vector<int> const & vec_name)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i<vec_name.size(); i++){
    cout << vec_name[i] << " ";
  }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why add const? i just changed int with void and removed return statement and it works

Comment: const in the parameter name ie (vector<int> const & vector) means the function cannot modify the contents of vector, it can only read from it. const in the function name i.e printVector(...) const means that the function cannot change any member variables inside the class.

Comment: it is not useful in this situation, but. when working on a larger code base it is a good habit.

Comment: what about the second `const` ?

Comment: @IdontReallywolf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141087/what-is-meant-with-const-at-end-of-function-declaration

Comment: please accept my answer - note that I have updated it to add a return character - this is so if you call printVector() again it will print on a new line.

Comment: This code gives an error because of the `const` after function `\n` wasn't really needed but.. seems to fit there. `error: non-member function cannot have 'const' qualifier`