# C++ Using cin in member functions of a class

Tags: c++

I am trying to use cin to read private members of a class within a member function of the class and i am getting an error [Error] no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin >> ((const Course*)this)->Course::courseID'  ?
Is it possible to do that? Here is my code

```
//Course.h
#ifndef Course_H
#define Course_H
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Course
{
    private:
        string courseID;
        string courseName;
        int credits;
        Course * nextCourse;
    public:
        void EnterCourse() const;
        void SetNext(Course *);
        string GetCourseID() const;
        string GetCourseName() const;
        int GetCredits() const;
};

void Course::EnterCourse() const
{
    cout<<"=======Enter Course Information========\n"
        <<"Enter Course ID: \n";
    cin>>courseID;
    cout<<"Enter Course Name: \n";
    cin>>courseName;
    cout<<"Enter credits: \n";
    cin>>credits;
}



string Course::GetCourseID() const
{
    return courseID;
}

string Course::GetCourseName() const
{
    return courseName;
}

int Course::GetCredits() const
{
    return credits;
}

void Course::SetNext(Course * cou)
{
    nextCourse=cou;
}



#endif
```

Comment: It is not directly about `cin` but you are trying to change the member variables in a `const` function. That's not possible for anyone but `cin` got the blame here.

Comment: It is not possible to modify members of a class in member functions declared `const`.   That includes reading members from `cin`.

Comment: `using namespace std;` in a header file is grounds for a formal reprimand in my book

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::cin` is considered writing to member data. But you can not change the data members using a `const` qualified member function. Remove the `const` specifier from the function declaration and definition if you want to achieve that functionality:

```
void Course::EnterCourse();
```

More info on the subject in these SO posts:
[Meaning of “const” last in a C++ method declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration)
[What is meant with “const” at end of function declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141087/what-is-meant-with-const-at-end-of-function-declaration)

Comment: Thanks very much got it