# C++ [ ] Index Operator Overloading As Accessor and Mutator

Tags: c++, indexing, operator-overloading

```
template <class TYPE>
class DList
{
    //Declaring private members
    private:
    unsigned int m_nodeCount;
    Node<TYPE>* m_head;
    Node<TYPE>* m_tail;

    public:
    DList();
    DList(DList<TYPE>&);
    ~DList();
    unsigned int getSize();
    void print();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void insert(TYPE data);
    void remove(TYPE data);
    void clear();
    Node<TYPE>*  getHead();
    ...
    TYPE operator[](int); //i need this operator to both act as mutator and accessor
};
```

i need to write a template function which will do the following process:

```
// Test [] operator - reading and modifying data
cout << "L2[1] = " << list2[1] << endl;
list2[1] = 12;
cout << "L2[1] = " << list2[1] << endl;
cout << "L2: " << list2 << endl;
```

my code cant work with

```
list2[1] = 12;
```

i get  error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value ERROR.
i want the [] operator to be able to make list2's first index node value 12

MY CODE:

```
template<class TYPE>

     TYPE DList<TYPE>::operator [](int index) 
    {
        int count = 0;
        Node<TYPE>*headcopy = this->getHead();
        while(headcopy!=nullptr && count!=index)
        {
            headcopy=headcopy->getNext();
        }

        return headcopy->getData();
    }
```

Comment: Operator `[ ]` usually has two overloads, not one.  You need to implement both.  [See example here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)

Comment: Also, your code won't work if `DList<T>` is passed as `const` and you tried to use `[ ]` in any aspect.  That's why you need the second overload.

Comment: can you show me in the example?

Comment: `void SomeFunc(const DList<int>& d) { std::cout << d[0]; }`  -- Try that.  None of the functions for `[ ]` will work, even the one you claim is working now.  Instead you will get a compiler error.  To solve that, you need the `const` overloaded version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my code cant work with
>
> ```
> list2[1] = 12;
> ```
>
> i get  error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value ERROR. i want
>   the [] operator to be able to make list2's first index node value 12

In C++, we have what is known as [Value Categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). You should make the operator return by reference. Hence, change your declaration from:

```
TYPE operator[](int);
```

to:

```
TYPE& operator[](int);
```

I am assuming that `headcopy->getData();` equally returns a reference to a non-local variable.

---

As PaulMcKenzie noted, you'll equally need an overload that works with a `const` `this`, aka, `const` member function overload. Hence we have:

```
TYPE& operator[](int);
const TYPE& operator[](int) const;
```

See [What is meant with "const" at end of function declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141087/what-is-meant-with-const-at-end-of-function-declaration) and [Meaning of "const" last in a C++ method declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration)

Comment: `[ ]` will still fail to work if `DList` is passed as `const` to a function.

Comment: so besides TYPE& operator[](int); this implementation, i need a second implementation for my [ ] operator to work for  list2[1] = 12;?

Comment: @ZuhMenzo, the `const` *member-function* overload is needed to make that operator work when calling it from `const` object. See the links in my answer

Comment: i got your point but still list2[1] = 12; when this line is executed regardless list 2 const or not 1st nodes value must become 12 when i debug it still enters TYPE& operator[](int); this function

Comment: i didnt overload = operator so i somehow need to understand when  [ ] is used with = or not

Comment: i understood now damn this is clever as hell, thanks