# const best practice in function declaration

Tags: c++

Ive searched through the archived posts but I couldnt find anything similar.

Just a simple question: whats the best practice in declaring inspecting functions like:

```
int foo(int a) const { return a+1; }
```

Im referring to the const keyword, do you usually declare it at the end of an inspecting function? Im just asking because I usually do, even if 99% I wont declare any const class.. I just keep on tellin myself that it could save me some time if I ever should need to, but I was wondering if anybody else really cares about declaring const functions or if Im just paranoid about typesafe code

Comment: What do you call an *inspecting* function?

Comment: ah.. just a way to call a method that doesnt change any object member

Comment: That function doesn't access any members, so it should probably be `static` instead.

Comment: static and const methods are not really the same, besides, I said a function that doesnt CHANGE any member, not access

Comment: But you provided an example of a method that doesn't access anything besides its parameter, therefore it should be `static`. I'm not saying all `const` methods should be `static`, I'm just saying the method in your example should be.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157458/using-const-in-classs-functions.

Comment: I see, you didnt read the last four lines. If you stop at the example, yes you-re right

Comment: @DanielDaranas thanks but this is not a question about whats the meaning/usage of the const keyword, I was just wondering if anybody else cares about declaring const functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about member functions (non member functions cannot be `const` ever), you should write *const-correct* code always, and that means that each and every function that does not modify the visible state of the object should be `const`.

Even if you don't ever create a constant object of the type, in many cases you will pass the object to a function through const references and in that case, only `const` member functions can be called on the object (Incidentally this means that you should pass the object by constant reference to any function that does not need to change the state of the received object)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you should if you want your program to support const correctness.

Const correctness has a way of propagating through your program once you begin declaring instances as `const`. As program complexity and your use of `const` increases, then you will either:

- encounter many compiler errors when using const objects if you do not add them now
- or your program will build without (or fewer) errors once you favor using `const` in the appropriate places.
- or you may end up avoiding `const` for some time - which is (IMO) not a good road to go down if you want to improve your designs.

Over time, many of us have learned to use `const` in more than 1% of our code.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` appended at the end of the function declaration and definition indicates a contract between the caller of the function and the function that the function will not modify any members of that class.

So if your function provides guarantee for such an const-correctness contract you should extend it to users of your function.

Comment: thanks but this is not a question about whats the meaning/usage of the const keyword, I was just wondering if anybody else cares about declaring const functions

Comment: @user815129: Every Good C++ Programmer does.